cannot checkpoint docker container
I am trying to checkpoint a docker container that is running code in the terminal :
docker checkpoint create w22 checkpoint

I am always getting an error :
Error response from daemon: Cannot checkpoint container w22: runc did not terminate successfully: exit status 1: criu failed: type NOTIFY errno 0 path= /run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/moby/d0885a112d3027c8e73b26e64db024f8accc31e1e72c40b01896b431cab38317/criu-dump.log: unknown

visiting the logs I find :
(00.164733) sockets: Searching for socket 0x113da8 family 2
(00.164736) Error (criu/sk-inet.c:191): inet: Connected TCP socket, consider using --tcp-established option.
(00.164769) ----------------------------------------
(00.164786) Error (criu/cr-dump.c:1674): Dump files (pid: 308411) failed with -1
(00.164794) Waiting for 308411 to trap
(00.164799) Daemon 308411 exited trapping
(00.164808) Sent msg to daemon 3 0 0
pie: 19: __fetched msg: 3 0 0
pie: 19: 19: new_sp=0x73024c332108 ip 0x730268408e26
(00.164863) 308411 was trapped
(00.164881) 308411 was trapped
(00.164887) 308411 (native) is going to execute the syscall 15, required is 15
(00.164900) 308411 was stopped
(00.165124) net: Unlock network
(00.165129) Running network-unlock scripts
(00.165133)     RPC
(00.223913) Unfreezing tasks into 1
(00.223929)     Unseizing 308331 into 1
(00.223937)     Unseizing 308362 into 1
(00.223988)     Unseizing 308408 into 1
(00.223998)     Unseizing 308411 into 1
(00.224075) Error (criu/cr-dump.c:2098): Dumping FAILED.

adding tcp-established in ~/.criu/default.conf is not changing anything.
I am searching everywhere but I feel like I am going in circles and nothing is solving the issue and there is not much documentation nor examples about people checkpointing docker containers that have TCP connections. Thank you in advance.
